# How do I link two separate buttons in a main activity to two separate activities?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm making an app in which the main activity has two buttons. I would like to connect each button to a separate activity. The following is my code:

```
package com.example.aadit.hexdropper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        openGalleryActivity();
    }
});


}

private Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCameraActivity();
        }
    });

public void openGalleryActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void openCameraActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
} 
}
```

The problem is occurring in the

```
private Button button2;
```

string. I don't understand how to fix it. The first string works fine, as everytime I click the first button, it takes me to the correct activity. However, inputting the second set of code makes the first set fail to work. What should I do to ensure that both buttons can go to their respective activities?

Comment: what kind of error? and why are there 2 `onCreate` methods?

Comment: The error is that the first string stops working when I input the second one. I created a second onCreate as that's what worked the first time. I (probably falsely) assumed that the same set of code that worked the first time would work again. I messed up there. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know hou did you make two onCreate methods, but acctually you can have only one. It should look like this:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button1;
private Button button2;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGalleryActivity();
        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCameraActivity();
        }
    });
}
```